# Many-to-Many update, Django signals

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, signals

I have these models (simplified):

```
class Product(TimeStampedModel):
    product_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, )
    shop = models.ForeignKey('Shop', related_name='products', to_field='shop_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    category = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='products', to_field='category_name', on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    brand = models.ForeignKey('Brand', related_name='products', to_field='brand_name', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    shops = models.ManyToManyField('Shop', related_name='shops')
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', related_name='categories')

class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    shops = models.ManyToManyField('Shop')

class Shop(models.Model):
    shop_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

In `admin` I am trying manually to change a `Category` for bunch of selected `Products` (I have a custom function for that). But here I see 2 problems:
1) Must be updated M2M relation in `Brand->Category`, if there was no `Brand` with this `Category`.
2) Must be updated M2M relation in `Category->Shop`, if there was not this selected `Category` in the `Shop`.
**How to do this in the best way?** I know that this might be some kind of *Django signals* use, specially `m2m_changed`, but I can't understand who is emitter of the signal, and who is receiver, and how to update multiple tables after change in 1 table.